# Images disapears while translating on hover first image in grid bootstrap (chrome only)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to find the source of this weird behaviour but have not been lucky so far.

My problem:

In chrome (it works fine in firefox), when I hover over the first image in a grid of 3x2 images ([like in this test page](http://peterstreef.nl/test_images.html)) the image and sometimes surrounding background images dissapear while it is translating. After it is done the images re-apear. This only happens in chrome, while scrolled down past a specific point (to test just scroll down all the way).

So far the only solution i have found is to turn off the translation alltogether which is not ideal but more of a last resort.

Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong?

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="SHIELD - Free Bootstrap 3 Theme">
        <meta name="author" content="Carlos Alvarez - Alvarez.is - blacktie.co">
        <title>Peter Streef</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="test/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="test/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test/assets/css/icomoon.css">
        <link href="test/assets/css/animate-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="test/assets/img/favicon.png">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="test/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test/assets/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="test/assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="test/assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#navbar-main">
        <!-- ==== SECTION DIVIDER2 ==== -->
        <section id="photography" class="section-divider textdivider divider2">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Photography</h1>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <!-- container -->
        </section>
        <!-- section -->
        <!-- ==== photography ==== -->
        <div class="container" >
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <br>
                <h1 class="centered">Photos I made</h1>
                <hr>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
            <!-- /row -->
            <div id="photography_row" class="row"></div>
            <!-- /row -->
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready (function () {
                $.ajax ({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'show_photos_test.php',
                    data: '',
                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (msg) {
                            document.getElementById("photography_row").innerHTML = msg;
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById("photography_row").innerHTML = "Error in loading photos.";
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test/assets/js/retina.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test/assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test/assets/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test/assets/js/jquery-func.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**(partial) PHP/HTML**:

```
foreach($photos as $photo)
{
$newTitle = wordwrap($photo['title'], 20, "<br />\n");
?>
    <!-- PORTFOLIO IMAGE 1 -->
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <div class="grid mask">
            <figure>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo($assets_folder.$photo['image']);?>" alt="">
                <figcaption>
                    <h5><?php echo($newTitle);?></h5>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#photo_modal_<?php echo($photo['id']);?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Read more</a>
                </figcaption><!-- /figcaption -->
            </figure><!-- /figure -->
        </div><!-- /grid-mask -->
    </div><!-- /col -->


     <!-- MODAL SHOW THE PORTFOLIO IMAGE. In this demo, all links point to this modal. You should create
          a modal for each of your projects. -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="photo_modal_<?php echo($photo['id']);?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo($photo['title']);?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo($assets_folder.$photo['image']);?>" alt=""></p>
            <p><?php echo($photo['description']);?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

    <?php
}
```

**CSS for the desired behavior**:

```
.no-touch .mask figure img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}
/*@PS added for touch 
.no-touch & no hover and .touch added
*/
.touch .mask figure img
{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
}

.no-touch .mask figure:hover img,
.mask figure.cs-hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
}

.no-touch  .mask figcaption {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}

.touch .mask figcaption {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
}

.no-touch .mask figure:hover figcaption,
.mask figure.cs-hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
}

.mask figcaption a {
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: make a fiddle.. its really difficult to make out without html.

Comment: @Gaurav I've added all the code I think is relevant. If you're missing something let me know!

Comment: @p.streef does this happen after the page and all the images have finalized loading? The only time I'm able to reproduce is if I clear cache, refresh and hover over the images before they have loaded. After they are loaded they are perfectly fine.

Comment: I see the same as MathiasaurusRex. It only does that when the images are loading. Looks like you are using 1920x1080 (!!!!) and sizing them down. Try it with thumbnail sizes and see if you get better performance.

Comment: I have the same behaviour while and after loading the page... I was planning on downsizing the images too, but It should work properly (it did before, and still does on firefox). It does however also happen to the 4th image while loading with clean cache (and perhaps others).

Comment: i don't have the answer to your question but i really like your site! good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppress the `position: relative;` from the `.grid figure img` selector at `main.css`:

```
.grid figure img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    /* position: relative; */
}
```

It will work just fine, assuming its default value: `position: static;`.

Comment: This answer may be incorrect - he appears to have a Heisenbug.  When you right-click and inspect his element in Chrome, the issue disappears, simply by opening the inspector.  That usually means it is a problem with the image loading, and probably the transform firing on an empty image.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle Possibly. Since I can't verify it myself, let the OP give us some feedback on it.

Comment: This did not completely fix the issue, but made it a lot less occuring for some reason. After adding thumbnails it works like a charm!

Comment: @p.streef Nice! Thank you for the feedback! BTW... Congratulations! Your site is really great!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have many large images, then you can try to control the layout with css before the images are loaded.  You can script it something like:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".preload").each(loadImages);

    function loadImages (i, elem) {

        var numItems = $('.preload').length;
        for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {

            $("#img" + i).each(function(){
                var thisSource = $(this).data('src');
                $(this).html('<img src="' + thisSource + '" alt=""/>');
            });
        }

    }
});
</script>


<span id="img1" class="preload" data-src="images/portfolio1.jpg"></span>
<span id="img2" class="preload" data-src="images/portfolio2.jpg"></span>
```

The idea is to get the layout css completed before your images are inserted.  There are many methods for doing this, but you will need to manage your image loading in portfolio somehow.